# What would this enum pattern be called?

Tags: java, enums

I use this technique frequently but I'm not sure what to call it. I call it associative enums. Is that correct?

Example:

```
public enum Genders {

    Male("M"), Female("F"), Transgender("T"), Other("O"), Unknown("U");

    private String code;

    Genders(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static Genders get(String code) {
        for (Genders gender : values()) {
            if (gender.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
                return gender;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could write code like that!

Comment: It's not a pattern. It's just regular code that understands that enums are classes. I also do that frequently, but I would name the enum Gender (without s), and throw an IllegalArgumentException instead of returning null to be consistent with valueOf()

Comment: What specifically are you referring to here as the "pattern?"  Is it the fact that you have a `get` method?

Comment: I would call it not following the naming convention which states that an enum, since it's a class, should be singular (eg. `Gender`) :) I don't see this being a pattern though, it's just a key/value mapping to an enum..

Comment: I wouldn't loop over it, but add a Hashmap for `get()`. Memory is cheap.

Comment: Well, now that I think of it, the get method is a factory method for the Gender enum. This is how you could call it.

Comment: @erikb You have to be careful with the Map because it has to be static but static fields in an enum class are not guaranteed to be created before instances of the enum. In fact, you cannot reference them inside the constructor. You end up needing to create an static inner class with the static Map within it to be able to do what you describe.

Comment: @IanNewson Yeah. In fact you can use this technique to associate multiple values as well.  It's good in situations where you might have if/else/elseif kinds of constructs since you can use a switch with the enum instead and get better performance.

Comment: @erikb There's no need for that. The enum already has an EnumMap built-in. In this case I want have a a case-insensitive match but you can always use the valueOf method instead.

Comment: that's good to know, thanks. then you could write a wrapper that uppercases the input String and then applies it to `.valueOf()`, right?

Comment: @DanHoward But the EnumMap that is built in is based on the name of the enum not some arbitrary value as is written here. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that looks a fair bit like the [Multiton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern).  If you do as  erikb suggests and use a map instead of looping, I would say it's *exactly* like the Multiton Pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I have a set of classes for doing this but I don't have a name for it other than `Encodable`

```
interface Encodable<T>{
    T getCode();
}

public class EnumUtils{

      public static <U, T extends Enum<T> & Encodable<U>> T getValueOf(
            @Nonnull Class<T> enumClass,
            @Nullable U code){

            for (T e : enumClass.getEnumConstants()){
               if (Objects.equal(e.getCode(), code))
                  return e;
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No enum found for " + code);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is a very, very simple parser.